# iOS caching objects from a async web request

Tags: ios, caching, asynchronous

My understanding on threading on iOS is not the greatest.

I am trying to create a caching service that allows us to connect to a webAPI and cache the results from a async request.

As the request can take some time to complete, i don't want another thread doing another service call for the same resource. I'm using a lock per resource.

As the resource is fetched in a async  manor, I'm also using a dispatch_semaphore_t per resource that waits until the async call has completed before return with the resource

On the off chance that the request is cancelled, [using AFNetworking 2] i would like to not hold up the thread so i'm awaiting with a time interval.

For my underlyingCachObject, i'am using CachKit.

I want to allow multiple thread access to different resources, but only one thread fetching a single resource and only block threads wanting that same resource.

With this soln, I'm current blocking the thread that is used to access the getOrAdd method - which could be the main thread.

Im not sure how i would go about deferring it onto a different thread and running the return statement back on the same thread that was used in the calling context.

```
@objc class xxxCache: NSObject , xxxCacheProtocol{

var underlyingCache:CKCache?

func getOrAdd(cachKey:xxxCacheKey, retrieveObject:(addObject:(protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>) -> Void, mustCall:(errored:Bool)->Void) -> Void) -> GetOrAddResult
{
    if let objectInCacheFirstTry = underlyingCache?.objectForKey(cachKey.key)
    {
        return GetOrAddResult(success: true, returnObject:objectInCacheFirstTry)
    }
    else
    {
        var returnObject:protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>? = nil;
        var hasErrored:Bool = false;

        objc_sync_enter(cachKey);
        if let objectInCacheSecondTry = underlyingCache?.objectForKey(cachKey.key)
        {
            returnObject = objectInCacheSecondTry
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(cachKey.semaphore)
        }
        else
        {
            let addObject = { [unowned self](objectToAdd:protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>) -> Void in
                self.underlyingCache?.setObject(objectToAdd, forKey: cachKey.key)
                returnObject = objectToAdd;
            }

            let mustCall = {(errored:Bool) -> Void in
                hasErrored = errored
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(cachKey.semaphore);

            }
            retrieveObject(addObject:addObject,mustCall:mustCall);
        }

        let timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(Double(cachKey.lockInMicroSecond) * Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)));
        let value = dispatch_semaphore_wait(cachKey.semaphore,timeout)
        objc_sync_exit(cachKey);
        return GetOrAddResult(success: (value == 0 && !hasErrored), returnObject:returnObject);
    }
}

func remove(cachKey:xxxCacheKey)
{
    objc_sync_enter(cachKey);
    underlyingCache?.removeObjectForKey(cachKey.key);
    objc_sync_exit(cachKey);
}
}
```

This would be used in the following way

```
@objc class xxxDeviceManager: NSObject, xxxDeviceManagerProtocol {

var deviceService:xxxDeviceServiceProtocol?

var applicationCache:xxxCacheProtocol?

func requestDevices(callBack:(Bool, [xxxDevice]?) ->Void)
{
    guard let applicationCache = self.applicationCache, deviceService = self.deviceService else
    {
        return;
    }

    let result = applicationCache.getOrAdd(xxxCacheConstants.devicesKey) { (addObject, mustCall) -> Void in
        deviceService.getDevicesWithSuccess({ (successful, retrieveDevicesWebResult) -> Void in
            if(successful)
            {
                if let devices = retrieveDevicesWebResult?.devices where devices.count > 0
                {
                    addObject(devices);
                }
             }
            mustCall(errored: !successful);
        })
    }
    callBack(!result.success, result.returnObject as? [xxxDevice])
}
}
```

Object that i'm using with the above:

```
@objc class xxxCacheKey : NSObject
{
    let key:String;

    init(key:String, lockInMicroSecond:Int64 = 10000) {
        self.key = "nz.co.xxx.xxxxxxxx.cachekey.\(key.lowercaseString)";
        self.lockInMicroSecond = lockInMicroSecond;
        super.init();
    }

    let semaphore:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    let lockInMicroSecond:Int64;
}

@objc class xxxCacheConstants : NSObject
{
    static var devicesKey:xxxCacheKey = xxxCacheKey(key:"devicesKey");
}

@objc class GetOrAddResult : NSObject
{
    init(success:Bool, returnObject: protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>?)
    {
        self.returnObject = returnObject;
        self.success = success;
        super.init();
    }

    var success:Bool;
    let returnObject: protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>?
}
```

I am also not sure if i should be using objc_sync_enter/exit or a NSRecursiveLock.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after much to-ing and throwing... 
I think i have come up with an answer that is more complicated than is needed using dispatched groups, queues and semaphore.

With the answers below I have managed to use a NSOperationQueue.currentQueue() to return the object onto the calling queue. I couldn't find any other way to do this as there is no guaranty that the calling queue will be the main queue.

Reading other answers on SO, I came to the conclusion that I should be moving away from the NS*Lock object in favour of dispatch queue.

but i still cant seem to figure what I could use instead of dispatch_semaphore to make sure that one operation is used to get the required resource.

Result:

```
func getOrAdd(cachKey:XYXCacheKey,  retrieveObject:(addObject:(protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>) -> Void, mustCall:(errored:Bool)->Void) -> Void, completeHandler:(result:GetOrAddResult) -> Void)
{


    if let objectInCacheFirstTry = underlyingCache?.objectForKey(cachKey.key)
    {
        return completeHandler(result: GetOrAddResult(state: .Success, returnObject:objectInCacheFirstTry))
    }
    else
    {


        let currentQueue = NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {[ unowned self] () -> Void in

            cachKey.lock.lock()

            let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
            let group = dispatch_group_create();
            var returnObject:protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>? = nil;
            var state:GetOrAddResultState = .Success;

            if let objectInCacheSecondTry = self.underlyingCache?.objectForKey(cachKey.key)
            {
                returnObject = objectInCacheSecondTry;
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_group_enter(group);

                dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in

                    let addObject = { (objectToAdd:protocol<NSCoding, NSObjectProtocol>) -> Void in

                        returnObject = objectToAdd;
                    }

                    let mustCall = { (errored:Bool) -> Void in

                        if(errored)
                        {
                            state = .Error
                        }
                        dispatch_group_leave(group);
                    }
                    currentQueue?.addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                        retrieveObject(addObject:addObject,mustCall:mustCall);
                    });
                })
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {() -> Void in

                let timeSpan = Int64((cachKey.lockInSecond * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeSpan));
                dispatch_sync(queue, {() -> Void in

                    if let object = returnObject
                    {
                        self.underlyingCache?.setObject(object, forKey: cachKey.key, expiresIn: XYXCache.defaultTimeInterval)
                    }

                    currentQueue?.addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                        return completeHandler(result: GetOrAddResult(state:state, returnObject:returnObject))
                    })
                    cachKey.lock.unlock();
                });
            });
        })
    }
}
```

with object used within the method:

```
@objc class XYXLock:NSObject, NSLocking {
let semaphore:dispatch_semaphore_t


init(resources:Int = 1) {
    semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(resources)
    super.init();
}

func lock()
{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}

func unlock()
{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
}
}

@objc class XYXCacheKey : NSObject {
let key:String;

init(key:String, lockInSecond:Double = 5) {
    self.key = "nz.co.XYX.XYXmobile.cachekey.\(key.lowercaseString)";
    self.lockInSecond = lockInSecond;
    super.init();
}

let lockInSecond:Double;
lazy var lock:NSLocking = {
    return XYXLock()
}();
}
```